# Query to count number of total fields in multiple rows that are greater than 0

Tags: mysql, sql

My layout of the database is like this.

```
id(primary key) | serial | channel | level1 | level2 | level3 | level4 | updated (datetime field)
```

For every serial I have anywhere from 4 to 8 channels.  I can view all this data by giving this query

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT channel, level1, level2, level3, level4, updated
FROM levels 
WHERE serial='013-315-122' 
ORDER BY channel DESC) 
AS q1 
GROUP BY channel 
ORDER BY channel
```

The data is updated multiple times a day, so that way the above query gives me the latest data only.  What I'd like to do is to be able to count the number of fields in level1, level2, level3 and level4 that are greater than zero for a serial number.  Keep in mind that each serial has 4 to 8 channels so I would want to select all the channels for a serial and count the total number for each of the level fields that are greater than zero.

I know how to do this for a single row, just not sure how to do this for multiple rows all together to get a grand total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what your desired output is, but maybe something like this is what you want?

```
SELECT 
    serial, 
    SUM(
       CASE WHEN level1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       CASE WHEN level2 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       CASE WHEN level3 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       CASE WHEN level4 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    ) ActiveChannelCount

FROM levels 
WHERE updated = (
  SELECT MAX(updated) 
  FROM levels l2
  WHERE levels.serial = l2.serial 
  AND levels.channel = l2.channel
  GROUP BY serial, channel
) 
# AND serial='013-315-122' 
GROUP BY serial
ORDER BY serial
```

Output would be like:

```
serial               ActiveChannelCount
-------------------- ------------------
013-315-122          11
999-315-122          15
```

See this sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2fdc/1)

Comment: That works perfect, only thing I need resolved now is how do I select only the latest entries in the database.  So data is for the same 4-8 channels is added every few hours, so I only want to do a count on the latest data based on the time in the updated field.

Comment: @Kevin Please take a look at it now.

Comment: Wow, you are a God amongst men!  Thank you soooo much, I was struggling with this for so long and you knocked it out like it's nothing!

Comment: @Kevin Happy to help :) It's just experience, nothing celestial ;)